# Service written in php stops working

Tags: php, service, websocket, server, phpwebsocket

I have written a php script that acts as a messageserver. The messageserver uses websockets in order to establish connections between multiple mobile applications in order to provide realtime chat capabilities between the different applications.

The main layout of my messageserver.php script looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

class chatServer extends WebSocketServer {
var $usersCache = array();
var $userConnectionIds = array();
var $dbconnect;

public function setDatabaseConnection($connect) {
    $this->dbconnect = $connect;
}

private function addMessage($convId, $from, $to, $message, $read) {
    ..
}

protected function process ($user, $message) {
    $parsedMessage = json_decode($message, true);
    switch($parsedMessage["type"]) {
        case "handshake" :
            $this->usersCache[$parsedMessage["userId"]] = $user;
            $this->userConnectionIds[$user->id] = $parsedMessage["userId"];
            break;
        case "chatMessage" :
            $receivingUser = $this->usersCache[$parsedMessage["to"]];
            if ($receivingUser != null) {
                $returnValue = $this->send($receivingUser, json_encode($parsedMessage));
            }
    }
}

protected function connected ($user) {

}

protected function closed ($user) {
    $userId = $this->userConnectionIds[$user->id];
    unset($this->userConnectionIds[$user->id]);
    unset($this->usersCache[$userId]);
    var_dump($this->usersCache);
}
}

$chatServer = new chatServer("0.0.0.0","36092");
global $connect;
try {
    $chatServer->setDatabaseConnection($connect);
    $chatServer->run();
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    $echo->stdout($e->getMessage());
}
```

and in order to keep the messageserver.php running on my server I use

```
nohup php messageServer.php > php.log 2>&1 &
```

This should allow the service to keep on running even when I close my ssh connection to the server, which is indeed the case. Now my problem is that this setup works as expected without any issues. However after some time the php script just stops running without any message at all. The php.log file does not contain any kind of error or termination message. Does anybody know what could be going on here? Is there any way to track why a service stopped running? Thanks!

Comment: I think the only way to track this down is to temporarily add debugging statements that write the current state variables and database status to a log file every minute or so.  If that doesn't work, add more debugging statements for the functions when they're called.  Something is killing your process and we need to find out what it is.  It could be a lost database connection or a function choking on a bad parameter passed to it or a line of code with an invalid reference or something.

Comment: I'm no expert, but in my time as a PHP coder (long ago), PHP processes were naturally short lived. The Http server would either extend the process's lifetime or initiate a new process for the new Http requests. Initiating a new process could fail if the previous process hand't closed the listening socket and the resource wasn't released... PHP has it's strengths, but long running processes aren't one of them. I would consider switching to Ruby, node.js or Python for the websocket layer.

Answer (score 0):

First off, don't use nohup for the PHP process. If you want to keep it alive? Use screen. As mentioned previously, add some debugging statements throughout the code.

Another advantage of using screen: you can reattach to the session (screen -r) and see output/whatever. So, do this: screen . Then run your program - php whatever.php . Then just close your connection and go on about your way. When it breaks? Login and do "screen -r" to reattach and see why it soiled its pants.

Also, why would you write this in PHP?? :) I mean, I'm not anti-PHP. I use it a LOT, and I'm very fond of it. But each language is simply a tool in the toolbox, and I certainly wouldn't use a hack saw to cut down an entire tree. Either use Node.JS if it's going to be a smaller-scaled server, or C if it's going to be hundreds of thousands of users. PHP is not the appropriate language, IMHO, for this.